# Incrementally replace a given string

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

Let us say I have a text like so below:

```
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
AC(nn)
```

Now I want to replace the `nn` with numbers like so

```
AC(0)
AC(1)
AC(2)
AC(3)
AC(4)
AC(5)
AC(6)
AC(7)
AC(8)
AC(9)
AC(10)
```

I used `M-x replace-regexp nn RET \# RET` to accomplish this.

Questions:

1. I want to start the replacement number to start from `1` rather than from `0`. Or rather start from a specified number say `25`. How should I modify the above command?
2. How to replace `nn` with digits like `001`, `002` .... `998`, `999`etc - I mean with leading zeros

Comment: This isn't what you're asking for, but another way of doing this is to use a macro along with a register.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### General technique

Your replacement string can contain arbitrary lisp code. From the [documentation for replace-regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html):

> In interactive calls, the replacement text may contain ‘\,’ followed by a Lisp expression used as part of the replacement text.  Inside of that expression, ‘\&’ is a string denoting the whole match, ‘\N’ a partial match, ‘#&’ and ‘#N’ the respective numeric values from ‘string-to-number’, and ‘#’ itself for ‘replace-count’, the number of replacements occurred so far, starting from zero.

We can use this technique in a number of ways.

### Starting from `1`

Wat we want to do is replace `nn` with one more than the `replace-count` you used with `\#`.

Call `#'replace-regexp` with the argument `\,(1+ \#)`:

`C-M-% nn \,(1+ \#)` will replace nn with `1` first, then `2`, `3`, etc.

### Starting at `25`

You can modify this by not just adding one, but (in your example) 25:

`C-M-% nn \,(+ 25 \#)`

### Leading zeros

Or we can use [`format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html) to add leading zeros. This will replace `nn` with `000`, `001`, `002`, etc. You can combine other lisp code above to start at `001`, `025`, or whatever you want.

`C-M-% nn \,(format "$03d" \#)`

Comment: This is fantastic! Do you know if it's possible to do the same with incremental *letter* replacements? That is `a`, `b`, and so on. I suppose using elisp to convert `\#` would do, but Emacs doesn't seem to have a built-in number-to-ascii-character conversion function...

Comment: Found out. In case others would like to replace with letters: the replacement string/elisp should be `\,(message "%c" (+ 97 \#))`. With `97` we start at `a`, because that's "a"`s ascii number; check any ascii table if you want to start at some other letter.

Comment: @pglpm Emacs Lisp supports character literals as `?a`. So instead of `(+ 97 \#)`, you can use `(+ ?a \#)`. It's much more readable. Note that Emacs doesn't have a character datatype; it simply has integers that it treats in some cases as characters.

Comment: Fantastic again, thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `cua-mode`.

Select the rectangle région (all the nn) and then `M-x cua-rectangle-mark-mode`.

Next, `M-n` and accept the default values.

Comment: I wish I could accept this as an answer as well