# How increment specific value in text

Tags: text

windows 10, Emacs 26.1

Suppose I has the next text

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "finished": 1573550444.4444,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "finished": 1573550444.4444,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "finished": 1573550444.4444,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "finished": 1573550444.4444,
    "orgn": 17
  }
]
```

I need to increment only field "**id**"

The result must be like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "finished": 1573550444.4444,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "finished": 1573550444.4444,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "finished": 1573550444.4444,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "finished": 1573550444.4444,
    "orgn": 17
  }
]
```

Is it possible? 
Without create my custom function.

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate (besides the other one that you posted today), but I don't have time now to look for it.

Comment: @NickD No: replacing by successive integers is not the same thing as replacing by a value constructed from the original value.

Comment: Cross-referencing with https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52780/replace-placeholder-by-incremental-value , which isn't a duplicate, but is sufficiently similar that there are equivalent answers posted in each.

Comment: Also see: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37898/incrementally-replace-a-given-string/37899#37899, for another similar question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [regular expression replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html#Regexp-Replace) with a bit of Lisp code. In the replacement text, you can use `\,(…)` to execute some Lisp code, and you can use `\#` as the number of replacements made so far. So `\,(+ 2 \#)` will be become successively `2`, `3`, `4`, … in successive replacements.

Thus, use `C-M-%` or `M-x replace-regexp` to replace `\("id": \)[0-9]+`
with `\1\,(+ 2 \#)`

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
(defun cummulative-raise-regexp (&optional regexp)
  (interactive)
  (let* ((regexp (or regexp "\"id\": \\([0-9]+\\),"))
     (counter 1))
    (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
      (replace-match (concat "\"id\": "(number-to-string (+ counter (string-to-number (match-string-no-properties 1))))","))
      (setq counter (1+ counter)))))
```