# How to increment number in every matching line?

Tags: text

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "finished": 1,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "finished": 2,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "finished": 3,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "finished": 4,
    "orgn": 17
  }
]
```

I need to increment every field `finished` by 1

The result must be:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "finished": 2,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "finished": 3,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "finished": 4,
    "orgn": 17
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "finished": 5,
    "orgn": 17
  }
]
```

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate, but I don't have time now to look for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How increment specific value in text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53736/how-increment-specific-value-in-text)

Comment: @Drew It may be a duplicate but not of that one: here the goal is to replace each N with N+1, there the goal is to replace each site with increasing values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following key sequence:

<kbd>M-C-%</kbd> `\("finished":[[:space:]]*\)\([0-9]+\)` <kbd>RET</kbd>
`\1\,(1+ (string-to-number \2))`<kbd>RET</kbd>

- <kbd>M-C-%</kbd> is bound to `query-replace-regexp`.
- `\("finished":[[:space:]]*\)\([0-9]+\)` is the regexp to search for, the first group is just for copying into the replacement string, the second group is the number to be transformed.
- `\1\,(1+ (string-to-number \2))` is the replacement string (`\1\,(1+ (read \2))` would also work).

  - `\1` copies group 1 at the head of the search string.
  - `\,(...)` evaluates the form `(...)` and inserts the result at the position of the escape sequence.
  - The Elisp transforms the string from group 2 (i.e., the string with the number) into a number and adds 1. The result is automatically translated back to a string that is inserted into the replacement string.

Comment: There's a bit of syntactic sugar you can use to simplify the replacement: you can substitute `\#2` for either `(string-to-number \2)` or `(read \2)`. So the whole replacement becomes `\1\,(1+ \#2))`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to use the function found [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementNumber).

```
(defun increment-number-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (skip-chars-backward "0-9")
  (or (looking-at "[0-9]+")
      (error "No number at point"))
  (replace-match (number-to-string (1+ (string-to-number (match-string 0))))))
```

For a quick solution, I would use a macro. This is appropriate if you only need to do it a small number of times, and the number of replacements is small.

First, go to the beginning of the file: <kbd>M-S-<</kbd>.

Now, we can record the macro. I'm going to search forward for the next instance of `"finished"`, go to the end of the line, go back two characters, then run the command `increment-number-at-point`.

<kbd>C-x ( C-s finished C-e C-b C-b M-x increment-number-at-point RET C-x e</kbd>.

You can then keep pressing <kbd>e</kbd> to repeat this macro until you get to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything needs to be done in pure elisp or using just Emacs facilities. In this case, I would use `shell-command-on-region` (usually bound to <kbd>M-|</kbd>): first mark the region of interest and then type <kbd>M-|</kbd> and pass the following shell command to it (followed by <kbd>RET</kbd>):

```
awk -F ":" '/finished/ {n = $2+1; printf "%s: %s,\n", $1, n; next;} {print $0;}'
```

In words: use a colon as a field separator, for each line, if the line matches `finished`, increment the second field and print out the modified line, then go immediately to the next line; otherwise, just print the line. There are probably shorter ways to do it, and perhaps some error checking needs to be added (e.g. if the second field on `finished` lines is missing or not a number), but in the case you showed, this should be enough.

Running `shell-command-on-region` with that command will produce output in a separate buffer, where you can check and make sure that it did the right thing. Once you are sure it is doing the right thing, you can *replace* the original region with the modified text using a <kbd>C-u</kbd> prefix on `shell-command-on-region`:

```
C-u M-| awk -F ":" '/finished/ {n = $2+1; printf "%s: %s,\n", $1, n; next;} {print $0;}' RET
```

`shell-command-on-region` allows you to use all sorts of tools outside Emacs to do text processing, so IMO it is an indispensable tool in one's tool box.